# Charge carrier injection in heterostructures - help with concept definition

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

I have this report to do on "Charge injection in heterostructures". I have been searching and reading but I still have some trouble with the basics, i.e. defining the concept.

As far as I understood a heterostructure is a junction between two or more different semiconductors and the carrier injections comes in the sense of bringing electrons and/or holes to the heterostructure through some kind of contact as a way of making a current or a light emitter by electron-hole recombination.

So the first question, is this correct?

What is difference between this and conduction through a metal-semiconductor contact? Is there such thing as a metal-heterostructure contact?

Does electron-hole pair formation by light counts as charge injection?

Can you advise me with some bibliography about this topic?

What is super-injection?

I'm really having trouble expanding this concept in details.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more or less correct.

Metal-semiconductor contact is called [Schottky barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_barrier) and is a different story as electron gas in metal is highly degenerate.

Electron-hole creation by light normally called excitation. Or optical pumping. Not injection.

Any book called "Physics of semiconductor devices" will be Ok. The one written by Simon M. Sze is the most classical I think.